# How to plot graph from known array of xs and array of ys in Octave?

Tags: graph, plot, octave

I need to draw several graphs for my report. How can I draw graph, if x and y pairs are saved in a file. Is it possible to directly read values from file and draw a graph? Example x,y pairs:

```
0.0 -0.1436521
0.2013266 -0.06703765
0.4026532 -0.08619126
0.60397977 -0.08619126
0.8053064 -0.10534488
1.0066329 -0.12449849
1.2079595 -0.095768064
1.4092861 -0.047884032
1.476395 -0.02873042
1.5099494 -0.06703765
1.5770583 -0.009576807
1.6106128 -0.038307227
1.6777216 -0.019153614
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `load` to read the data into an array, and `plot` to plot it.

For example (assuming the data file is called 'data.txt'),

```
octave:9> data = load('-ascii', 'data.txt')
data =

   0.00000  -0.14365
   0.20133  -0.06704
   0.40265  -0.08619
   0.60398  -0.08619
   0.80531  -0.10534
   1.00663  -0.12450
   1.20796  -0.09577
   1.40929  -0.04788
   1.47639  -0.02873
   1.50995  -0.06704
   1.57706  -0.00958
   1.61061  -0.03831
   1.67772  -0.01915

octave:10> plot(data(:, 1), data(:, 2))
```